# Connect payload cms with vercel postgres in Nextjs 14 project

Tags: postgresql, next.js, vercel, payload, payload-cms

I am trying to add cms to my NextJs 14 project and I have decided to go with Payload cms as it should be fully integrated in the future with NextJs and Vercel. I followed the instructions on this video from Payload to connect Payload to Vercels postgres https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjOKuGabFiQ
All seems to be functioning except that I am lost on how to use it as an API for my project and push it to production so I can access it via Vercel deployed domain.